ML model from Edge Impulse runs 5 times slower after porting it from Arduino IDE to ESP-IDF on ESP32
I've been struggling with this one for a while so here we go :
I've been trying to match the speed of inference for an ML model I generated with Edge Impulse originnaly to Arduino, then to ESP-IDF for my ESP32-CAM device.
The algo takes ~1300ms to run on Arduino and  it takes ~6600ms on ESP-IDF with -Os optim in both case. The closer I got is by setting compile optimization to -O2 which got me around 2000ms on ESP-IDF.
In both cases the CPU frequency is set at 240MHz, and I tried to figure out how exactly does Arduino compiles and mimic it  to see what I could miss but I'm I'm not figuring it out.
I verified with a test sample that does matricial calcul with both volatile floats and integers to ensure that the CPU calculus capacities are the same in both envs and I got :
I have similar results on both projects and logged everything thread related and it matches (runs on core1, same priority, same cpu speed).
I ensured that memory allocation is static in both tensor flow lite lib with the flag -DTF_LITE_STATIC_MEMORY.
I ensured that there is no parallel shinanigans and OPEN_MP is disabled in both cases.
I switched compilers to check if it doesn't come from a compiler libc or something.
I tried to get as close as possible as Arduino's compiler arguments.
Here is a dump of arduino compile flags arduino compile arguments :
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-c' '-mlongcalls' '-Wno-frame-address' '-ffunction-sections' '-fdata-sections' '-Wno-error=unused-function' '-Wno-error=unused-variable' '-Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable' '-Wno-error=deprecated-declarations' '-Wno-unused-parameter' '-Wno-sign-compare' '-Wno-enum-conversion' '-gdwarf-4' '-ggdb' '-freorder-blocks' '-Wwrite-strings' '-fstack-protector' '-fstrict-volatile-bitfields' '-fno-jump-tables' '-fno-tree-switch-conversion' '-std=gnu++23' '-fexceptions' '-fno-rtti' '-w' '-Os' '-v' '-w' '-E' '-CC' '-D' 'F_CPU=240000000L' '-D' 'ARDUINO=10607' '-D' 'ARDUINO_ESP32_DEV' '-D' 'ARDUINO_ARCH_ESP32' '-D' 'ARDUINO_BOARD="ESP32_DEV"' '-D' 'ARDUINO_VARIANT="esp32"' '-D' 'ARDUINO_PARTITION_huge_app' '-D' 'ARDUINO_HOST_OS="windows"' '-D' 'ARDUINO_FQBN="esp32:esp32:esp32cam:CPUFreq=240,FlashFreq=80,FlashMode=qio,PartitionScheme=huge_app,DebugLevel=none,EraseFlash=none"' '-D' 'ESP32' '-D' 'CORE_DEBUG_LEVEL=0' '-D' 'BOARD_HAS_PSRAM' '-mfix-esp32-psram-cache-issue' '-mfix-esp32-psram-cache-strategy=memw' '-D' 'ARDUINO_USB_CDC_ON_BOOT=0' '-D' 'ESP_PLATFORM' '-D' 'IDF_VER="v5.1.4-497-gdc859c1e67-dirty"' '-D' 'MBEDTLS_CONFIG_FILE="mbedtls/esp_config.h"' '-D' 'SOC_MMU_PAGE_SIZE=CONFIG_MMU_PAGE_SIZE' '-D' 'UNITY_INCLUDE_CONFIG_H' '-D' '_GNU_SOURCE' '-D' '_POSIX_READER_WRITER_LOCKS' '-D' 'configENABLE_FREERTOS_DEBUG_OCDAWARE=1' '-D' 'TF_LITE_STATIC_MEMORY' '-I'

Here are my compile line on esp-idf :
 C:\Espressif\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf\esp-12.2.0_20230208\xtensa-esp32-elf\bin\xtensa-esp32-elf-g++.exe -mlongcalls -Wno-frame-address -DNDEBUG -fdiagnostics-color=always -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-error=uninitialized -DTF_LITE_STATIC_MEMORY -mlongcalls -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fstrict-volatile-bitfields -fno-jump-tables -fno-tree-switch-conversion -fno-rtti -w -Wall -Werror=all -Wno-error=unused-function -Wno-error=unused-variable -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-enum-conversion -gdwarf-4 -ggdb -mfix-esp32-psram-cache-issue -mfix-esp32-psram-cache-strategy=memw -Os -freorder-blocks -fmacro-prefix-map=path -fmacro-prefix-map=other_path -DconfigENABLE_FREERTOS_DEBUG_OCDAWARE=1 -std=gnu++2b -fno-exceptions  -DESP32=ESP32 -MD -MT file.cpp.obj -MF file.cpp.obj.d -o file.cpp.obj
-c file.cpp

What is the more strange for me is the difference between -o2 optimization in my ESP-IDF case, but Arduino is better with -Os...
Anyway any help would be greatly appreciated,
Have a good day everyone and thanks for reading me,
Aloïs

Profile it. Find the nottleneck

If the code executed from IRAM or serial FLASH? Is FPU enabled?

Thanks for your answer I'm adding profiling rn.
For FPU The ESP32 is based on the Xtensa architecture with  LX6 cores, which do not have a dedicated FPU.
About the IRAM, I did nothing to specify functions in it, but I think neither did the Arduino. Do you have an advice about how to check it ? Straight from map file ?

ESP32-S3 has FPU

HA ok sorry, but I work with an older generation an ESP-32S Module

Long story short, it was the TFLITE kernel accelerated maths functions that weren't compiled because the flag that defines the boards wasn't always passed by the CMake file.
If you find your problem looks similar, look for the  EI_CLASSIFIER_TFLITE_ENABLE_ESP_NN flag and ensure your board is always defined.
